# Coding the labyrinth solver

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, python

The question mathematically has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886084/guaranteed-graph-labyrinth-solving-sequence/4887473#4887473

To summarize, in an unknown strongly connected, directed graph in which all vertices have out-degree 2 (so from a vertex, we either go $a$ or $b$), we are placed on one of the vertices (we do not know which, as we don't even know the graph), and have to find the exit, which is one of the vertices (of course we do not know this either). We must find a sequence of $a$, $b$ that guarantees our getting out.

Now, the way to solve this (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4887473/1098363) was very well written under my previous question, so let me quote it:

> There are only finitely many possible labyrinths on n
> vertices, where the data defining a labyrinth includes all of the edges, the start vertex, and the target vertex. Say there are $M$ labyrinths, and name them $L_1,L_2,\dots,L_M$
> . Given a labyrinth $L$
> and an arbitrary vertex $v$
> of $L$
> , let $sol(L, v)$
> be a sequence of $a$
> and $b$
> which, starting from $v$
> , takes you to the exit of $L$
> .

> Let $w_1=sol(L_1,v_1)$
> , where $v_1$
> is the start vertex of $L_1$
> . The first part of the solution path will be $w_1$
> .

> Let $v_2$
> be the vertex you end up on after following the path $w_1$
> on the labyrinth $L_2$
> . Then, let $w_2=sol(L_2,v_2)$
> . The second portion of the solution path is $w_2$
> ; as long as the true labyrinth is $L_2$
> , then we will be done after completing $w_1+w_2$
> .

> Let $v_3$
> be the vertex you end up on after following the concatenation of paths $w_1+w_2$
> on the labyrinth $L_3$
> . Then, let $w_3=sol(L_3,v_3)$
> . The third portion of the solution path is $w_3$
> .

> We continue in this fashion. Assuming that $w_k$
> has been defined, we let $v_{k+1}$
> be the result of following the path $w_1+w_2+\dots+w_k$
> on $L_{k+1}$
> , and then define $w_{k+1}=sol(L_{k+1},v_{k+1})$
> .

> Finally, the solution path which works on any labyrinth is $w_1+\dots+w_M$

And this makes perfect sense, it is probably not the shortest such sequence, and that is fine. I have to write the code that outputs this sequence of $a$ and $b$, and this seems like a daunting task.

I believe the task can be split up into multiple parts:

**Step 1: generate the graphs**: This seems hard, do i do it the irreducible matrix way or is there something that relies more on programming that is easier? Should I do adjacency list or matrix?

**Step 2: make a path finding function**: Depending on the format of the graphs I belive this should be fairly easy with BFS or DFS

**Step 3: execute the iteration**: This seems pretty difficult. After enumerating these graphs I also have to have a function that keeps track of where in the graph we are, based on the previous sum of $w_i$ then do the BFS or DFS to the terminal and save that sequence and move on to the next graph

Is this plan correct programming-wise? Can someone help me especially with Step 1, as I don't know how this could easily be done?

(I also had this post but it was much less concrete: [Graph labyrinth solving sequence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/167241/graph-labyrinth-solving-sequence))